# Python - How to correctly get content between two offset in a file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, offset

I'm trying to get content between two offset (essentially part of a file). For that, I found [fileslice](https://github.com/alghafli/fileslice) to be useful.

For testing I'm using a file called `hello` with the string:

```
helloworld
```

I left a newline deliberately since I'm doing testing on different things.

Using this code:

```py
from fileslice import Slicer
import sys

r = open('hello', 'r')

slicer = Slicer(r)

start = int(sys.argv[1])
size = int(sys.argv[2])
fileslice = slicer (start, size)
    
sys.stdout.write(fileslice.read())
```

Anyway, the problem I'm facing is that, when using certain offset range, it seems like the wrong character represented by the offset get displayed...:

```
:~/fileslice$ wc -c hello # using wc to check the size
11 hello
:~/fileslice$ python -u "/home/user/fileslice/testslice.py" 0 11 | xxd # works
00000000: 6865 6c6c 6f77 6f72 6c64 0a              helloworld.
:~/fileslice$ python -u "/home/user/fileslice/testslice.py" 0 10 | xxd # works
00000000: 6865 6c6c 6f77 6f72 6c64                 helloworld
:~/fileslice$ python -u "/home/user/fileslice/testslice.py" 1 10 | xxd # doesn't work as expected
00000000: 656c 6c6f 776f 726c 640a                 elloworld.
```

Here I'm using the previously mentioned test file and code and pipe the output to `wc` (to check the size) then after that, do a couple testing and checking the output in Hex with `xxd`.

As it can be seen, the one commented "works" work as expected, as in, i can get the content between the two offset just fine.

But for the last one, where i wanted to get content between the char `e` (in this case offset `1`) which "work" but then, notice that the previously discarded newline (offset `10`) appear again, contrary to the previous test which worked fine/as excepted...

How can i correctly get content of a file using two offset? (start/end)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Size is the distance between the two offsets i.e. end minus start.

`size = int(sys.argv[2]) - int(sys.argv[1])`